# Lines not showing in d3.js multi-line-chart with time axis

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Hello nice people of SO,

I'm pretty new to javascript, JSON and D3.js and I'm trying to build a multi-line time series chart. My data comes as JSON from my server like this:

```
{
"t":    ["2014-08-16T16:15:00", "2014-08-16T16:20:00", "2014-08-16T16:25:00", ...], 
"todd": [0,0,1,2,3,2,1,0,0, ...],
"pete": [3,2,1,0,4,4,0,0,0, ...]
}
```

This I store in an array called 'dataset'. The datetimes are subsequently parsed. 't', 'todd' and 'pete' arrays are of equal length.

Ultimately I want the time (t) values to be used for the x-axis, the other two as y values over time. Parsing the data works, however I can't get it to display properly. What works so far is:

A: display my values one after the other without a reference to time, so I get two nice, colored lines but the x-axis holds no information, as it just displays 0 to N.

OR

B: have the x-axis show as a timeline based on the "t"-values (this tells me that the parsing works as it should). However, I can't get my two lines to show.

In Variant A I was simply returning the index as x value like so:

```
var line = d3.svg.
    .x(function(d,i) { 
        return i;
    })
...
```

Now I'm trying to return the datetime from my "t"-array:

```
var line = d3.svg.
    .x(function(d,i) { 
        return dataset.t[i];
    })
...
```

However, nothing is displayed. I get no errors at all in the console. I tried console logging the value of 'dataset.t[i]' but nothing shows. It's as if the code isn't even running so here is the for loop that calls the above code:

```
for (var key in dataset) {
  if (dataset.hasOwnProperty(key) && key!="t")  {
    data=dataset[key];
    svg.append("svg:path").attr("d", line(data))
        .style("stroke", color(key))
        .style("stroke-width", 2);

    //BELOW IS IRRELEVANT TO MY QUESTION, JUST FOR COMPLETENESS...
    svg.append("rect")
          .attr("x", w - 65)
          .attr("y", n*25)
          .attr("width", 10)
          .attr("height", 10)
          .style("fill", color(key)); 

    svg.append("text")
          .attr("x", w - 50)
          .attr("y", n * 25 + 10)
          .attr("height",30)
          .attr("width",100)
          .style("fill", color(key))
          .text(key);
    n+=1; // counter up
    }
};
```

I can tell this is running as the 'rect' and 'text' elements are added to the chart.

The full code is here: http://pastebin.com/tbS7rD7p

By now I can't see straight anymore so I'm really looking forward to your ideas. Many thanks in advance!

Cheers, Ben

Comment: I would definitely run the loop on your dataset and establish the keys before the .data() method. Your code will be much more efficient. See if you can get the data in the key/pairs you need it first. did you try console.log(data) after your key var expression?

Comment: thanks! what exactly do you mean? that i should create a "dictionary" (I think it'd be an object in JS) consisting of (t, value)-pairs and pass that to the line function? and what do you mean by .data() method? can't find it... cheers

Comment: I just looked, and I don't see where you've entered the data for the svg. After you append the svg group, you'll want to give the selection its data object to bind to the lines you are drawing. See https://www.dashingd3js.com/binding-data-to-dom-elements for more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, in code veritas, for your input. I'm in the process of optimizing the code in the way you suggested. However, it seems you do not need the .data() method with lines as you allocate the data via .x() and .y() methods for these (if I understand correctly).

Anyway, in the end the solution was to change:

```
.x(function(d,i) {return dataset.t[i];})
```

to

```
.x(function(d,i) {return x(dataset.t[i]);})
```

which is mentioned in pretty much every tutorial but which I, wisely ^^, chose to ignore because it seemed pointless to me. If anybody can comment on that and enlighten me, I'd be grateful.

Cheers!

Comment: for anyone reading this in the future: I now understand D3 a bit (!) better than before. although you can allocate the data directly via .x() and .y() without using the .data() method it is not the way D3 is meant to be used. i found this [link](http://www.delimited.io/blog/2014/3/3/creating-multi-series-charts-in-d3-lines-bars-area-and-streamgraphs) to be very useful if you're starting out with D3.js and want to build a multi-series chart.